# Searching for a badge to track progress on results in dozens of the same badge

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-badges, badge-progress

#### Steps to replicate

1. Navigate to your profile
2. Click on the "Choose which tag badge to track" gear icon
3. Search for a tag name

#### Expected results

- The tag badges for the matching tag will be displayed (bronze, silver, and gold).
- Only the tag badges matching the query will be shown (so for a perfect match, only three tag badges will be shown

#### Actual result

- The bronze badge is show dozens of times (see screenshot)
- No silver or gold version of the badge is shown at all.

[image: Searching for typescript in the "Select your next badge" popup, showing dozens of bronze typescript badges]

Comment: Haha that's hilarious.  Full repro on Chrome 53 Windows 10.  For reference, this doesn't seem to affect badges on meta, only on main SO.

Comment: Reproduced, although it will also show silver or gold badges if you search for a tag in which you already have a badge. For example, if I search for "javascript," I have the silver JavaScript badge already. So, my results are many copies of the gold `javascript` badge and equally many copies of the bronze `javascript-events` badge.

Comment: This is probably related to jQuery update. I reported it in [We have updated jQuery to 1.12.4 - please report related bugs here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285091/310998) on MSE.

Comment: This should now be resolved, please have another look.